# When using range() inside a for loop, in what procedure does the list instantiate?

Tags: python

I'm wondering about the `range()` function when used in a python `for loop`

```
for x in range(100):
    print x
```

Does range initialize the entire iter-able list before entering the loop or is it smart enough to generate the values as it increments?

In other words if I say.  Will there be overhead from very large ranges like such?

```
  for x in range(1000**1000):
      value = x
```

Comment: In which directory/file could I see the implementation of range()?  I would like to learn how Python works, but I don't know where to start reading code.

Comment: @Matt you can see it [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/rangeobject.c) for the CPython implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[In Python 3, range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) produces an "immutable sequence" not a generator or iterator

[In Python 2, range](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) generates a list Python 2 also has [xrange](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) to make an object which is an "opaque sequence" which has virtually no memory overhead but `xrange` is not available in Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the Python version:

- In Python 3, `range()` is a generator-like object that produces values on demand.
- In Python 2, `range()` creates a materialised list. If you want a generator-like object, use [`xrange()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange).

Comment: It's a little pedantic, but Python 3's `range` isn't really a generator or an iterator, which is why you can do `10**1000 in range(10**999)` instantly, and why `next(range(10))` generates `TypeError: 'range' object is not an iterator`.

Answer (score 1):

In case of any doubt, it is easy to check. In IDLE (e.g. using Python 3.3):

```
>>> r = range(10)
>>> print(r)
range(0, 10)
>>> print(list(r))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes! python initialize the entire iter-able list before entering the loop if `range()` is used. But there is an easy way of overcoming this overhead using `xrange()` which generate the values as it increments. This can be verified as:

```
>>> range(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> xrange(10)
xrange(10)
```